# Access objects in inlines or in the main admin for filtering

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I want to filter my selection in an inline.

model:

```
class Prob(models.Model):
project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
...
```

I got the admin.py like:

```
class MaterialInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Material

def  formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
if db_field.name == 'material':
kwargs['queryset'] = Material.objects.filter(project = request.???)

class ProbAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
inlines = [MaterialInline,]
```

"request.???" is my problem. I don't know how to access project. I tried something like request.GET.get('id_material__selected'), because the dropdownlist is called id_material. But it is not working.

Thanks in advance!